# Настройка почтового сервера на ubuntu

Tags: apache2, email, ubuntu

Приобрёл недавно VDS для проекта, всё настроил, кроме одного: отправку почты. 
Необходимо отправлять письма с сервера на другие адреса.

Сначала использовал sendmail - ничего не вышло, теперь - postfix.

Всё настраивал по инструкциям. В php.ini раскомментировал и поменял значение:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Тестировал в консоли:

```
echo "Test" | mail -s Testing my_mail@gmail.com
```

И в php - `mail()`.

Ошибок нет, но письма не доходят. Ну или я не знаю, где они должны отображаться.

**Подскажите, как определить причину, где смотреть ошибки, или что-нибудь ведь должно быть.** error.log или access.log я смотрел, ничего там нет, связанного с mail.

Техподдержка хостинга, понятное дело, ничего не говорит, отправляют на тариф с администрированием или говорят настраивать самостоятельно.

---

**UPD**

С удовольствием бы отказался от VDS, но горю желанием использовать websocket в проекте, а оно не поддерживается на обычном хостинге. Разные инструкции смотрел, уже третий вечер пошёл, когда пытаюсь настроить почту.

Вот из последних: http://www.8host.com/blog/ustanovka-i-nastrojka-postfix-na-ubuntu-14-04/

```
Содержимое /var/log/mail.log(вместо domain - мой домен, вместо my_mail - почта на которую отправляю):

...
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/pickup[2679]: 65C1F60B39: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/cleanup[3273]: 65C1F60B39: message-id=<20150318164350.65C1F60B39@domain.ru>
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/qmgr[1556]: 65C1F60B39: from=<www-data@domain.ru>, size=1349, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/error[3275]: 65C1F60B39: to=<my_mail@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4008:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/pickup[2679]: 8C9D860B3B: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/cleanup[3273]: 8C9D860B3B: message-id=<20150318164350.8C9D860B3B@domain.ru>
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/qmgr[1556]: 8C9D860B3B: from=<www-data@domain.ru>, size=1349, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 18 19:43:50 domain postfix/error[3275]: 8C9D860B3B: to=<my_mail@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4008:c01::1b]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

Comment: Логи по почтовику валяются в /var/log/mail.log, скорее всего, у вас не стоит почтовика вообще или не прописан MX-DNS. Но поверьте, вы не хотите настраивать почтовый сервер. Вы не представляете масштаба этой махины.

Comment: ссылку на инструкцию в студию! я просто ставлю apt-get postfix и сразу все работает. Собственно я уверен что все остальные сервера почты в ubuntu так же хорошо работают. Единственный вариант если ваш провайдер как-то блокирует исходящую почту. Хотя если у вас VDS не думаю, что такое они будут делать.

Comment: > Network is unreachable

ну, собственно, и всё.

Comment: DNS настраивал в панели управления хостинга, также как это было настроено на предыдущем аккаунте с обычным виртуальным хостингом(вместо ip - ип адрес сервера, domain - домен):
domain.ru. A ip 
localhost A ip 
mail A ip 
pop A ip 
smtp A ip
mx.yandex.ru. MX 10

Answer (score 1):

Ну дело вот в чем, насколько я понимаю:
т.к. отправляем НА my_mail@gmail.com, то from должно быть www-data@MYdomain.ru, а MX-запись ну ни как не yandex.ru, а соответствовать Вашему почтовому серверу
Читайте внимательно инструкции по настройке

Comment: mail.domain.ru MX 10

попробовал, ничего

smtp.domain.ru MX       10

аналогично

в панели управления написано, что адрес должен быть с точкой в конце, но когда пишу mail.domain.ru. то оно превращается в mail MX 10...

в ошибках добавилось такое(но остальное тоже осталось, вроде Network is unreachable)



Mar 18 21:44:38 domain postfix/smtp[4782]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.163.27]:25: Connection timed out

Я почему написал изначально mx.yandex.ru. MX 10, потому что на обычном хостинге такое прописано и его можно редактировать

Comment: Не знаю, какой хостинг Вы имеете в виду, но бывает так, что в качестве smtp-сервера используются сервера Гугл или иной компании, предоставляющей эти услуги. У Вас так? Или Вы собираетесь настроить свой smtp, если свой - то его имя будет не yandex а mydomain (ну или какое у вас доменное имя?) и на него прописывается MX-запись